# Ember store pushPayload with websockets

Tags: ember.js, websocket, store

I am using websockets to push some data to the client. I push this to the store by doing a pushPayload specifying the corresponding model. 
However pushPayload seems to be doing a PUT operation to update the server with this new information. I do not want this call to be made since there is no change in the data. Its just that the client got it from a different source.

Is there a way I can stop the PUT from being done? 
I am using Ember v2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed that there was an explicit save being called somewhere in the workflow. 
Pushpayload itself does not cause a save automatically.